# How can I create an .exe installer that installs an .exe version of my Java application?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, installation, exe

I have a Java application that already uses Maven to build automatically. I have tried using IzPack to get my end goal done, but I've been having a lot of trouble with it, so I am open to other options. I need both the installer and the application to be .exe or .bat and not Jar files.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Paul it's related, but not exact. I know how to convert a single jar to .exe using Launch4J. However, I'm hoping for a better solution for having both an .exe installer and .exe program. (Right now, I either have a lone .exe application without an installer OR an .exe installer that installs a Jar)

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and we came up with the solution to do the build in Maven first creating the exe with launch4j and then we created a plugin for InnoSetup that packages the app and the JVM folder all in one installer.

Comment: We plan to move to Spring Boot that should natively allow the creation of single file applications.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html